# Encode calldata for function with uint8 argument in ethers.js

Tags: javascript, ethereum, ethers.js

I'm trying to encode calldata using ethers.js for the following function:

```
function myFunction(uint8,uint8,uint256,uint256,uint256)
```

My code sample:

```
let iface = new ethers.utils.Interface([
        "function myFunction(uint8,uint8,uint256,uint256,uint256)"
    ]);
let callData = iface.encodeFunctionData("myFunction", [
            0,
            1,
            0,
            0,
            ethers.constants.MaxUint256,
        ]);
```

As a result, I get following calldata:

```
0xc4bc81b30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

I guess, it starts with function selector (8 bytes), then arguments (only uints) and it's possible to see that uint8-arguments take up the same amount of space as uint256-arguments (64 bytes). As a result, call with this calldata fails. How to encode it correctly?

Comment: Your question needs some details like which library and what encoding algorithm you are using